# Can i get any advantage from Athlon 64 3800 writing a concurrent program on Ada?

Tags: windows, concurrency, 64-bit, ada

I'm limited to ObjectAda 7.2 for particular reason. Do i need to install a 64 bit OS (Win 64x in my case) to write and run such programs?

Answer (score 1):

Is your goal just to write multi-threaded programs in Ada that can run concurrently on the multiple cores?

It depends on how your compiler handles Ada tasks, but IIRC that compiler maps Ada tasks to Windows threads, so it should work just fine with a 32-bit OS. The program itself probably wouldn't generate any different code for a 64-bit Windows than for 32-bit. To get any different, you'd need a 64-bit version of the compiler (which probably won't be OA 7.2). Aonix's current datasheet for OA doesn't even say anything about Vista or Win7 support.

You might consider going 64 bit to get more than 3 Gig of accessible RAM, but I don't think it will help your Ada code any.